# Tomcat with in eclipse not recognizing the non web.xml app

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat8, servlet-3.0, spring-tool-suite

I have created Spring MVC application without web.xml, completely using the java configuration but when I right click on the project I am not getting an option as Run on server which usually helps me to deploy my war into Tomcat 8.
[image: please refer below image]

Comment: I guess your project isn't configured as a dynamic web project in Eclipse/STS and therefore not recognized as web project to run on a server.

Comment: I configured as a dynamic web project. and I even created through spring legacy-spring web maven, it did not work for me

Comment: maybe provide the project as a sample project somewhere with a few steps how to reproduce the issue, so that we could take a more detailed look.